# Is this notice to update to Geth 1.6.6 via windows.net legitimate?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, security, network, mac-osx

A few days ago when opening Ethereum Wallet version 0.8.9 I received popup windows notifying me to update the Wallet to 0.8.10 and Geth to 1.6.6. Here is a screenshot of the latter:

[image: The Geth 1.6.6 update notice generated by the Ethereum Wallet points to https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net.]

This notice directs me to windows.net, but it appears [github is the official repository](https://ethereum.github.io/go-ethereum/downloads/#) and that the latest version is 1.6.7, not 1.6.6. Additionally, I am no longer receiving this notice, Ethereum Wallet > 'Check for Ethereum node updates...' has no effect, and Ethereum Wallet > 'Check for updates...' opens a window (after a brief waiting-animation) reporting, "No update found. You are running the latest version of Ethereum Wallet." However, I'm still using 0.8.9 according to Ethereum Wallet > 'About Ethereum Wallet'.

Is it simply not showing updates at the moment due to limitations (or blocked ports?) of the public business's hotspot that I am now checking at? (The notice appeared using a different non-public Internet connection.) Is windows.net an official download mirror for the Ethereum community?

Comment: Can't say why Ethereum-wallet is not showing updates. You can download the latest (currenty 0.8.10) from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reminder and link is legitimate, if you go to https://ethereum.github.io/go-ethereum/downloads/# and check the download link, it refers to ...core.windows.net

Ethereum Wallet doesn't update to the latest geth version automatically as soon as it's available, so the recommendation might be a version off.